# inserted + deleted in trigger sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, update, триггер, insert

Всем доброго времени суток!
Создаю триггер на обновление таблицы, при работе которого нужно в таблицу писать все измененные поля в поле другой таблицы в котором будет указано значение до/после изменений. 
Отдельно для вставки и удаления сделал, там довольно легко все выходит, а вот одновременно что-то никак, заранее спасибо!

Таблица допустим:

```
create table #A
    (
        Name nvarchar(max),
        Sex nvarchar(max)
    )
```

Comment: Как понять "одновременно"?

Comment: При обновлении появляются в памяти сразу две эти таблицы, и нужно сгенерировать что-то вроде i.field + ' ' + d.field

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO history_table (id, field_hist)
SELECT i.id, i.field + ' ' + d.field
FROM INSERTED as i
    LEFT JOIN DELETED as d ON i.id = d.id
```

Comment: Не все так просто, названия полей неизвестны